# analytical geometry - volume of tetrahedron

Tags: analytic-geometry, volume

Can someone please explain to me the meaning of this statement in relation to calculating the volume of tetrahedron ?

"We shall often get negative value for volume of a tetrahedron. We define the volume OABC to be positive if the rotation determined by ABC is anti-clockwise with respect to O" i.e

$Vol(OABC)=-Vol(ADBC)=-Vol(ABDC)=Vol(ABCD)$

And further, if i have three given point A,B and C, then volume of PABC should be $${1\over 6}|...|$$ or $$-{1\over 6}|...|$$

Comment: Depending on orientation volumes, areas and even distances in coordinate geometry may have negative signs. Think about distance in 1D, the simplest case, and why you need either absolute value sign, or a specific orientation convention to get positive results.

Comment: @macavity I understand that concept. However, i am not able to apply it for volume of tetrahedron. Can you suggest whether volume will be negative or positive for the case i have mentioned

Comment: If you need to distinguish signed volumes, think of the triangle $ABC$ and when its oriented area is considered positive - usually when $ABC$ is anticlockwise in orientation from a perspective - (why?).  Now this triangle divides space into two parts and depending on which part the fourth vertex is, you can consider a positive or negative sign for the area of the triangle, and hence the volume of the tetrahedron.  $$ --- $$If you need more clarity, you need to draw a figure explain the situation more - for e.g what is OABC, DABC and PABC - the same or different tetrahedrons?